# Understanding loop iteration in Ruby

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I have written this code to determine how many a's are present in a given input within a method:

```
def count_a(word)
  count = 0
  i = 0
  while i < word.length
    char = word[i]
    
    if char == "a" || char == "A"
        count += 1
    end 
    
    i += 1  
  end

  return count 
end

puts count_a("application")  # => 2
puts count_a("bike")         # => 0
puts count_a("Arthur")       # => 1
puts count_a("Aardvark")     # => 3
```

Can someone better explain why I need the `i += 1` at the bottom of the method? I have added to the count in the conditional above, so I just need some further knowledge on how the iteration becomes necessary outside the conditional and within the method.

Thanks!

The code failed to run without the i += 1

Comment: Don't forget `char.downcase == 'a'` or `case char` and `when /\Aa\z/i` which ignores case.

Comment: Try that most basic of debugging techniques, stepping through the program by hand. Write the results of each statement on a piece of paper. Don’t anticipate or intuit the outcomes, just follow the instructions literally, because that’s what the computer is going to do. Do this both with and without the line that has you puzzled. By the way, this is a major incentive to keep methods short and sweet — it’s no fun going through hundreds of lines of code by hand.

Comment: Now that your question has been answered you should consider posting your code at SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). At that forum you can expect to get excellent advice on how to improve your code by using an assortment of Ruby's many built-in methods. Answers there will also help you gain a better understanding of the Ruby way of thinking about coding problems.

Comment: If you don't ever increment `i`, the variable would always have the value 0,  and the condition for `while` would always be true, leaving you with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a decent first attempt. But its not really Ruby.

Ruby actually has tons of methods that lets you complete this without mutating an external variable:

```ruby
def count_a(word)
  word.each_char # enumerate over the chars
      .count { |l| ['a', 'A'].include?(l) } # counts the number of elements yielding a true value.
end
```

In general methods like `while`, `until` and `loop` should mainly be used when you're dealing with input or streams - in other words when you're not looping across an object with a known length. For everything else use the plethory of methods provided by [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) and the other core classes.

> Can someone better explain why I need the i += 1 at the bottom of the method?

Because otherwise the loop will run forever since `i < word.length` will always be true. But as a rule of thumb if you ever write `i += 1` in Ruby you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `word.count("Aa")`

Answer (score 1):

The line `i += 1` adds one to `i`.  If you remove it, then `i` will be stuck at 0 forever because you never change it.  Therefore, your loop will never terminate (in the case that `word.length` is positive).

Answer (score 0):

Any loop needs a test and an update. If the variables in your test never change, why would the loop ever end?

This method could be written far more idiomatically as follows. By downcasing the string first we don't have to check for `'a'` *and* `'A'`.

```
def count_a(word)
  word.downcase.count('a') 
end
```

As an intermediate solution, you can use `#each_char` to iterate over each character in the string.

```
def count_a(word)
  count = 0
  word.each_char do |ch|
    count += 1 if ch == 'a' || ch == 'A'
  end
  count
```

Be aware that a method returns its last expression, an explicit `return` is only needed to break control flow and return *early* from a method.

Comment: `word.count("Aa")`